# Tokenize a URL in C

Tags: c, parsing, url, tokenize, strtok

A URL is of the form

```
PROTOCOL://HOST:PORT?PARAM1=VALUE1&PARAM2=VALUE2&...PARAMN=VALUEN
```

I figured I could first tokenize on `?`, then tokenize on `&`, and then tokenize on `=`. Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: "better" in what aspect? Readability? Performance? Standard-compliance? etc.

Answer (score 4):

Use a library such as [uriparse](https://uriparser.github.io/).

Here’s how to use the library (taken from the [documentation](https://uriparser.github.io/doc/api/latest/)):

```c
UriUriA uri;
const char * const uriString = "file:///home/user/song.mp3";
const char * errorPos;
if (uriParseSingleUriA(&uri, uriString, &errorPos) != URI_SUCCESS) {
    /* Failure (no need to call uriFreeUriMembersA) */
    ...
    return ...;
}
/* Success */
...
uriFreeUriMembersA(&uri);
```